# Easy way to switch between multiprocessing and not with multiprocessing.Pool?

Tags: python, debugging, multiprocessing

I'm doing something like:

```py
with Pool(4) as pool:
  list(tqdm(pool.imap(func, iterable)))
```

But I'm getting an error at some point, and I can't see the trace. Rather than learning how to retrieve the trace which I will do at some point, I want to be able to at least change something so that it runs the code without starting a new process.

In another library (`torch` but not relevant) I can set `n_workers` to 1 and it acts as if I'm not using multiprocessing. I do that for debugging. So I could do:

```py
with Pool(1) as pool:
  list(tqdm(pool.imap(func, iterable)))
```

But here that doesn't seem to be the case. Is there anything else I can do in 0.5 seconds for debugging this?

Comment: Fastest fix is [multiprocessing logging](https://pypi.org/project/multiprocessing-logging/). Then    `pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=job_number, initializer=install_mp_handler)`

Comment: @forgetso if that's the fastest then there's no answer to my question explicitly and I believe of I modify my question to suit your answer this is a dupe. Thanks